# C++ file compiling: -L and -I arguments don't work for boost library

Tags: c++, boost, include, g++, include-path

There are similar questions but their answers did not work for my issue.
I have a c++ program with `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` on top (among other includes).

To compile correctly, if I understood, I should do the command:

```
g++ -g -L/path_to_boost_lib -lboost_lib myprog.cpp -o myprog.exe
```

If i do a locate, I get `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.`

Hence I edited my call to g++ by doing:

```
g++ -g -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_unit_test_framework myprog.cpp -o myprog.exe
```

But I still get errors of the type `undefined reference to boost::unit_test`.

I also tried the option `-I/usr/include/` which contains the boost folder, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the order. The GCC linker goes through the artifacts left-to-right, and every unknown symbol it encounters in an object file must be resolved by an artifact occurring afterwards.

The right command is thus:

```
g++ -g myprog.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_unit_test_framework -o myprog.exe
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/347964) for a more thorough explanation.

I suggest using a build tool like CMake that takes care of such low-level details for you.

Comment: I definitely will have a look, thank you! Is there a specific order between options '-L' and '-I'? I thought everything was blocked due to boost but it seems that my include path has some issue too... And I don't really understand because the include in my header is a relative path, i.e. `#include "../../folder1/folder2/otherfile.h` and this path is correct from my main program which I want to compile

Comment: Relative includes should not depend on `-L`, and I am unsure whether order matters here but if it does, `-L` certainly must come before `-l`. If you have a problem with relative includes in your code, you should ask a new question.